# How to create the correct json file for mobile app project

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

I'm not too familiar with JSON and I'm trying to create local JSON file for my Flutter Mobile app Project.

The way I plan to design my mobile app is, I will be displaying A list of Genre in my home page. When a user click a specific genre then it'll take to a new screen where it'll show all the song list that fall under those genre.

also I'll have another screen call "All songs" and it'll display all song with id order.

I have created this basic JSON file based on my knowledge and I'll be really appreciated if someone can review If this will work or I might need to modify it.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "songNumber": "1",
        "title": "Acadian Driftwood",
        "genre": "Jazz",
        "favorite": false
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "pageNumber": 2,
        "songNumber": "2",
        "title": "Alfie",
        "genre": "Musical/Film",
        "favorite": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "pageNumber": 3,
        "songNumber": "3",
        "title": "Ace Of Spades",
        "genre": "Rock/Pop",
        "favorite": true
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "pageNumber": 4,
        "songNumber": "4",
        "title": "Alison",
        "genre": "Rock/Pop",
        "favorite": false
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "pageNumber": 5,
        "songNumber": "5",
        "title": "Alabamy Bound",
        "genre": "Musical/Film",
        "favorite": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Most languages have a way to "[stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)" an object/dictionary, why not do that instead of manually writing the JSON?

Comment: Hi @JBallin thanks and I will take a look at ti but could you pls still show me how it should be done in JSON file also?

Comment: https://json.org, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Model to help you in this situation, then you can create a list of models and pass it to the next page.

below is a model you can use in your app:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Song songFromJson(String str) => Song.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String songToJson(Song data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Song {
Song({
    this.id,
    this.pageNumber,
    this.songNumber,
    this.title,
    this.genre,
    this.favorite,
});

int id;
int pageNumber;
String songNumber;
String title;
String genre;
bool favorite;

factory Song.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Song(
    id: json["id"],
    pageNumber: json["pageNumber"],
    songNumber: json["songNumber"],
    title: json["title"],
    genre: json["genre"],
    favorite: json["favorite"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "pageNumber": pageNumber,
    "songNumber": songNumber,
    "title": title,
    "genre": genre,
    "favorite": favorite,
};
```

}

Comment: Hi khaled, thanks for this but I already have the model. what I'm asking is does my json file look correct or not to be able to do what I want to do.

Comment: correct, and you can use it, but when you navigate to another screen  make sure that you pass model data with you and use it on second screen

Comment: Oh ok, So if I click "Jazz" category in the in the HomeScreen, it will be able to display all the song that related to Jazz in the next screen right?

Answer (score 0):

Use this website it is best to create a file directly from the JSON response or you can use the plugin in android studio jsonToDart

Answer (score 0):

```
 {

"data":[
{
    "id": 0,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "songNumber": "1",
    "title": "Acadian Driftwood",
    "genre": "Jazz",
    "favorite": false
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "pageNumber": 2,
    "songNumber": "2",
    "title": "Alfie",
    "genre": "Musical/Film",
    "favorite": false
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "pageNumber": 3,
    "songNumber": "3",
    "title": "Ace Of Spades",
    "genre": "Rock/Pop",
    "favorite": true
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "pageNumber": 4,
    "songNumber": "4",
    "title": "Alison",
    "genre": "Rock/Pop",
    "favorite": false
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "pageNumber": 5,
    "songNumber": "5",
    "title": "Alabamy Bound",
    "genre": "Musical/Film",
    "favorite": true
}
 ]
}
```

**that is the correct way of creating  json file**

Comment: This is just another way, not "correct" one, as JSON supports an array as a root element. So OP's json is also correct.

Comment: on his json he is directly adding array json that will create problems in directly parsin g the json but the object form he can easily parse the json